# Add values from datagridview cells

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have datagridview with values 0; 11,4; 2,3..... ;

How can i add values for example from two cells and send it to third cell?

```
            dataGridView1[3, 0].Value = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1[1, 0].Value) + Convert.ToInt16( dataGridView1[2,0].Value);
```

but this doesn't work

so for example in next cell i'll have 11,4+2,3=13,7.

Problem is in adding float values from datagridview cells.

Comment: Not clear, wat are the delimiters? the examples you gave are different.

Comment: I make unclear question -> check edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you convert to INT, when you have float? Try use this

```
dataGridView1[3, 0].Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[1, 0].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[2, 0].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
+ Convert.ToInt16( dataGridView1[i+1,0].Value); // +1
```

instead of

```
+ Convert.ToInt16( dataGridView1[i+2,0].Value);
```

You are assigning the result of the sum of the cell at index `i+0` and the one at index `i+2` to the cell at index `i+2`. I think you want to assign `i+0` and `i+1` to the cell at index `i+2`.

```
[ i+2] = [ i ] + [ i+1 ]
```

Comment: Yeah, i wrote a bad question - this third column is for example only, problem is in adding float values from datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
 row.Cells["col3"].Value = decimal.Parse(row.Cells["col1"].Value.ToString()) + 
                           decimal.Parse(row.Cells["col2"].Value.ToString());
}
```